# jsoup - how to make it stop encode my text

Tags: jsoup

I have a html with some characters encoded like **& #227;** (i've added a space between & and # to not get encoded) and i when i call **Jsoup.parse("N*& #227;O");**, it's transforms into **Não**.

I've tried options like:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(msgHtml.getBytes("UTF-8"));

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 4*1024);
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
r.close();
is.close();
String html = total.toString();

org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.outputSettings().charset("ISO-8859-1")
//doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8")
```

Can i avoid it and force Jsoup to ignore encode like these?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, If I do `System.out.println(Jsoup.parse("N*& #227;O").text());` I get `N*& #227;O`

Comment: Remove spaces between $ and #